# Using findElementById("elementID") with appium for native android app. Error: "Locator strategy 'css selector" is not supported"

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, appium, native

```
I am using Appium installed over npm (version 1.13.0), Selenium (3.8.1), Appium client for java (4.1.2).
```

Using UIAutomationViewer I am able to find IDs of elements I want to click. But when I run the code, in place od IDs, selenium is trying to find them with css.

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, 
"PixelTest");
capabilities.setCapability("platformName","Android");
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.AUTOMATION_NAME, 
"UiAutomator1");
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.NO_RESET, true);
capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.android.calculator2");
capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", ".Calculator");

driver = new AndroidDriver<AndroidElement>(new URL(url), capabilities);
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

driver.findElementById("digit_9").click();
driver.findElementById("digit_6").click();

driver.findElementById("pad_operator").click();

driver.findElementById("digit_1").click();
driver.findElementById("digit_0").click();  

driver.findElementById("eq").click();
```

Error I am having: "org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: Locator Strategy 'css selector' is not supported for this session". Why this happens?

Comment: My first guess would be that those do not look like complete id's.  Please add a screenshot of the uiautomator for the page in question to your original post.  Also, how do you declare the driver initially?

Comment: `protected AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> driver;` this is how driver is declared.
It don't matter if I put full id like `driver.findElementById("com.android.calculator2:id/digit_9").click();` it will return the same error about css selector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using incompatible [Selenium Java](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java) and [Appium Java](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.appium/java-client) clients combination.

Looking into [dependencies for Appium 4.1.2](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.appium/java-client/4.1.2) it appears that you need [Selenium 2.53.1](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java/2.53.1), other versions might not work due to [JAR Hell](https://dzone.com/articles/what-is-jar-hell).

[image]

Basically you need to have only **Appium Java** in your project classpath, if you're using a build system like [Maven](https://maven.apache.org) or [Gradle](https://gradle.org) - the other jars will be resolved via [Transitive Dependencies](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Transitive_Dependencies) mechanism.

I would also recommend upgrading to [Appium Client 7.0.0](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.appium/java-client/7.0.0), or whatever is the latest version [released](https://github.com/appium/java-client/releases).

Check out [Appium - Code Examples - Java](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TE/Java) for sample projects you can use as a basis.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It didn't occur to me to check the compatibility with Selenium. Since my project is Maven based, I just changed versions to match.